# Dynamically naming list in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to dynamically name the list and use that,I searched a lot but did not get the satisfactory answers how to do that.

```
if __name__=="__main__":

    lst_2017=[]
    lst_2018=[]
    lst_2019=[]


    for year in range(2017,2020):
        #avg_data is function which returns a list of number
        lst_"{}".format(year) = avg_data()
```

Error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-84-4c1fefedd83e>", line 9
    lst_"{}".format(year) = avg_data()
           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected :

loop will iterate 3 times and function return the 3 list in the respective lists

example:

```
 lst_2017=[1,2,4]
 lst_2018=[3,4,5]
 lst_2019=[3,4,6]
```

Comment: There's no need to create dynamically named variables. It is not useful. Consider using a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary instead of naming multiple dynamic variables. Then all your data is in one data structure and easily accessible from key/value pairs.

For the below example I simply [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) up the years and data together to construct a dictionary, where years are the keys and averages are the values.

```
avg_data = [[1,2,4], [3,4,5], [3,4,6]]

result = {}
for year, avg in zip(range(2017, 2020), avg_data):
    result[year] = avg

print(result)
```

Which can also be done like this, since `zip(range(2017, 2020), avg_data)` will give us `(year, avg)` tuples, which can be directly translated to our desired dictionary using `dict()`:

```
result = dict(zip(range(2017, 2020), avg_data))

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{2017: [1, 2, 4], 2018: [3, 4, 5], 2019: [3, 4, 6]}
```

You'll probably have to tweak the above to get your desired result, but it shows the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use dictionary with iter:

```
avg_data = [[1,2,4], [3,4,5], [3,4,6]] 
it=iter(avg_data)
d={}
for i in range(2017,2020):
    d["lst_"+str(i)]=next(it,None)

for k in d.keys():
    print(k, "=",d[k])
```